# WPF ModernUI and Extended Grid Conflict

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, modern-ui

I have a WPF Project with ModernUI (https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui) and i have a Window with Extended DataGrid (http://wpfextendeddatagrid.codeplex.com/).

The problem is that when I Implement AutoFilter The button to Filter doesn't appear.

Expected result:
[image: Expected result]

But what I get is this:
[image]

I can make the filter option work but to do it i need to comment out some line refering to ModernUI Themes on my App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.Light.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: What's the issue here? _i need to comment out some line_ which lines?

Comment: @Prajwal These lines in the config: <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.Light.xaml"/>
The issue is that the checkbox popuop to filter doesn't appear